# css and javascript not loaded when using htaccess

Tags: php, javascript, css, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My CSS and JS don't load when I use `.htaccess`

I use this:

> RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteBase /mysite/
>   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
>   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|css|images|robots.txt)
>   RewriteRule ^show/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?show=$1 [NC,L] # Process parrots

and myCSS link:

```
<link href="css/my.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Is there a way in order to make it work?

Comment: What do you think your rule means?

Comment: you need to specify on your RewriteCond which file type to handle.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.(php|html|htm)([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/`this would make the request only work for php, html, or htm extentions

Comment: I don't have a clue. i just want to rewrite my link to be  "localhost/root_folder/product/id_product"